# Sum of lognormal distributions

Tags: distributions, lognormal-distribution

I am to find the expected value, variance and, preferably, the distribution of the variable $z_n$, where $z_n$ is given by

\begin{equation}
z_n = \exp\left\{ \Delta t \sum_{i = 1}^n k_i \exp\left\{a_i x
\right\}
\right\},
\end{equation}
and $x$ is a random variable with Gaussian distribution and is the same for all values of $i$. Both $a_i$ and $k_i$ are known values.

Is there any way to approach this problem? Are all the $x$'s independent of each other if they do not vary for different $i$'s?

Comment: There is only one random variable on the right hand side and it is not indexed by i. There is no need to discuss independence here. I would approach this problem as finding moments/distribution of a function (here, $z$) of a single random variable (here, $x$).

Comment: It might be easiest to start with the moments of $\log(z_n)$ in terms of moments of $x$. How does this problem arise?

Comment: You write that "x is the same random variable", but in the title of the question you talk about the sum of (many) log-normal distributions. Also you raise the issue of independence. So to be safe, is "x" the same random variable for all $i$, or there are many $x$ -random variables that are identically distributed? And when you say "Gaussian", you mean the Standard Normal, or the Normal in general?

Comment: @Theja: How would you propose a method for finding the moments in this case, given that we have a sum of exponential functions inside another exponential function?
I have tried to find the distribution of $z_n$ by using the method described in [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables)
without any success, as I have trouble finding the inverse of $g^{-1}(z_n)$.

Comment: @Glen_b: This kind of problem arises when I try to integrate $z$ over a time period, $dz/dt =  k  e^{a x} z$. This gives me $z_1=z_0 e^{\Delta t k_1 e^{a_1x}}$, which leads to $z_n=z_{n-1}e^{\Delta t k_n e^{a_nx}}=\prod_{i=1}^n e^{\Delta t k_i e^{a_ix}} = e^{\Delta t \sum_{i=1}^n k_i e^{a_i x}}$. Here we have that $z_0 = 1$.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos: Yes, $x$ is the same variable for all $i$, and by Gaussian I mean Normal distribution in general, with known mean and variance.

Comment: There is something I don't understand here: it appears you are integrating in continuous time, treating $k$ and $a$ as constants with respect to the time index $t$, and then you discretize and treat $k$ and $a$ as varying along the discrete index $n$. Probably it is just me, but could you explain this part a bit further? (It would be better of course to include it in the main body of your question rather than in the comments). Thank you.

Comment: ...moreover, since you have movement along the time axis, you cannot treat the $X$ random variable as free of the index except if it is realized once in the beginning and this value remains constant throughout. Otherwise, it is realized at every $i$, and therefore you have a sequence of random variables, identically distributed, but taking possibly different values at each $n$.